# Fly problem in my house

Tags: pest-control

Not sure if this belongs here but it’s the closest I can find.

I discovered some flies in my food waste bin that our local authorities make us have and now I can’t stop seeing them, I find loads. I have since got rid of the bin completely.

I have tried spray but out right killing them I find the easiest and quickest way.

What is the best way in lockdown that I can get rid of them? Traps etc

Answer (score 1):

Flies (assuming common house flies) are attracted to gaseous chemicals released by decaying things. No decay, no flies. If you have removed the bin and they are still coming in, it's because there are still traces of decaying material attracting them. Clean everything with a strong household cleaner or a solution of diluted bleach.

Comment: Ok so I found the source but there is no decaying or rotting food. It is under my kitchen units just the occasional off cut of wood and dust under there. I’ve cleared out what I can and am killing them as soon as I see them so I’m hoping I’m towards the end of them now. I have traps galore arriving today after using the ones o had so I hope this will do the trick and hope they disappear after a few days

Comment: The next stage is to completely bleach under all the units with pure bleach and lemongrass oil and then leave out more traps (electric, sticky traps and chemical traps) and hope to god that fixes it